# C++ Caesar Encryption Project (ASCII)

Tags: c++, string, encryption, caesar-cipher

For class, I have to develop a Caesar encryption project in C++ that takes in a string, and shifts all the ascii codes by a random integer.  I have the project working perfectly, and the code is written below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    string sentence = "";
    int shifter, counter = 0, position = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    shifter = (rand() % 25) + 1;
    cout << "Enter a sentence, and this program will encrypt it: " << endl;
    getline(cin, sentence);
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        sentence[i] = sentence[i] + shifter;
        cout << sentence[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My only issue is that my teacher wants them to be shifted to only letters.  If the letter is 'z' and the shift is '2', she wants the output to be 'b'.  I am not sure how this would be done.

Is a simple procedure to this issue possible?  If so, how would it be done?

Comment: Are you familiar with the modulus operation?

Comment: @iProgramIt ok, so what is 28 mod 26?  The 28 is z + 2.

Comment: 2 would be the answer.

Comment: @iProgramIt and how would you map `2` to the third letter of the alphabet (we assume we start at `0`)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... Do you mean this: "sentence[1] = sentence[1] + 3;"?

Comment: See my above comment and see if you can figure out what's going on. You  have to realize that letter are just numbers, represented by an ASCII code. What you want is to wrap around the range of the numbers `a`...`z`. It's much better to try it yourself rather than seeing a solution here.

Comment: Got it. Makes sense. I'll let you know if it works. :)

Comment: @iProgramIt take also a look [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) to see how the chars are represented.

Comment: @iProgramIt sorry, small mistake, first you need to map the range to `0...25`, then mod by the number of letters in the alphabet, then map back to letters.

Comment: Please, please, please search before asking:  [Possible duplicates of Caesar Cipher](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+caeser+cipher&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+caeser+cipher&nfpr=1).  I've also answered a couple.

Comment: Something else to motivate the change in requirements: say shifter = 26 and someone enters a 'z': 'z' + 26 = 122 + 26 = 148, which is not ASCII so what should happen? Arithmetic on characters makes sense only over limited ranges and only for known character set encodings. (P.S., you are probably not using ASCII, anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to realize that letters will need to be mapped to numbers, rotated in some way and then mapped back to letters.

@vsoftco has already tried to get you on the right track with his comments, so read them carefully because he's giving you very nice hints.

I will try and fill in some blanks the @vsoftco has left out.

Here is how you would map a letter to a number:

```
char letter = 'B';
int number = letter - 'A';
```

Letters are just numbers which the computer knows to represent as letters. In fact the letter 'B' is 66 in [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). So if we do this in C:

```
char letter = 'B';
int number = 100 - 'B'; // <- this is equal to 100 - 66 which is 34
```

`number` becomes 34.

So this is nice but we want our numbers to be in the range between 0 and 25 (so that it is easy to apply the modulo operation).

Think about it. If you add 5 to an unknown number between 0 and 25 how do you make sure that the result will be less than 26? Use the modulo and it will *wrap* the operation for you.

But back to converting letters to numbers. To turn any capital letter (note that the lower case letters have different numbers) into a number between 0 and 25 you could subtract 'A' like this:

```
char letter = 'C';
int number = letter - 'A'; // <- this is 'C' - 'A' = 67 - 65 = 2 ( which is the 3rd number if we start counting from zero )
```

To convert back from numbers to letters just add 'A'.

```
int number = 5; // This is the 6th letter since we start counting from zero
char letter = 'A' + number; // Now letter is 'A' + 5 = 65 + 5 = 70 which is 'F'...
```

With this conversion and the modulo operation @vsoftco described in the comments you should be able to make a caesar algorithm on your own.

Answer (score 0):

May this will solve your problem :)
http://ideone.com/6AzY2i

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long int
#define MOD 1000000007

using namespace std;
char st[10000000], s[1000000];

int main(){
    cout << "Enter your Ceaser Chipher to decrypt:\n";
    cin >> s;
    ll t;
    t = strlen(s);
    ll n;
    strcpy(st,s);
    /*cout << "Shift of how many characters:\n";
    cin >> n;*/
    cout << "Shift in which direction (r(right) or l(left)) :\n";
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    srand(time(NULL));
    n = (rand() % 25) + 1;
    cout << "Your String is shifted by:" << n <<endl;
    ll f;
    if(c=='r'){
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(st);i++){
            f = st[i] + n;
            if(f>122)
                f = f - 26;
            st[i] = f;
        }
    }
    else if(c=='l'){
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(st);i++){
            f = st[i] - n;
            if(f<97)
                f = f + 26;
            st[i] = f;
        }
    }
    cout <<"Your encrypted String :-> "<< st <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```